# Flutter web Firebase Google Sign In not working

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin, flutter-web

I've been working with Flutter for a while now, and today I decided to try Flutter web. I wanted to make a website with Firebase Google Sign in. I followed all the steps from [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-web-firebase-authentication-and-google-sign-in-33ef84a70b71), but I couldn't get it to work. I don't get any errors but when I run the auth code nothing happens. 
I ran the app with `flutter run -d chrome --web-hostname localhost --web-port 5000`
I also tried opening `localhost:5000` in normal Chrome but it didn't work either.

Here is some information, if you need anything else please let me know, thank you.

`flutter doctor -v` output:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 1.26.0-2.0.pre.296, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.685], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.26.0-2.0.pre.296 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision 737496e8db (8 hours ago), 2021-01-12 02:54:03 -0500
    • Engine revision 10cee6abcb
    • Dart version 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-214.0.dev)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code (version 1.52.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.18.1

[√] Connected device (2 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 87.0.4280.141
    • Edge (web)   • edge   • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 87.0.664.66

• No issues found!
```

These are my `pubspec.yaml` dependencies:

```
...
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.19.0+1
  firebase_core: ^0.6.0
  flutter_auth_buttons: ^0.10.0
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.9
  http: ^0.12.2
  provider: ^4.3.2+3
...
```

This is my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    
    <script>
      var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "xxxxx",
        authDomain: "xxxxx",
        projectId: "xxxxx",
        storageBucket: "xxxxx",
        messagingSenderId: "xxxxx",
        appId: "xxxxx",
        measurementId: "xxxxx"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      firebase.analytics();
    </script>
    <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my auth code:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  String googleAccessToken, googleIdToken;
  AuthService(this._firebaseAuth);

  Stream<User> get authStateChanges => _firebaseAuth.idTokenChanges();

  Future<String> signOut() async {
    try {
      await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
      return 'success';
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      return e.message;
    }
  }

  GoogleAuthCredential getGoolgeCredential({accessToken, idToken}) {
    return GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: accessToken,
      idToken: idToken,
    );
  }

  Future<String> signInWithGoogle() async {
    /// This is the auth code
    try {
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();

      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
          await googleUser.authentication;

      googleAccessToken = googleAuth.accessToken;
      googleIdToken = googleAuth.idToken;

      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(getGoolgeCredential(
          accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken, idToken: googleAuth.idToken));
      return 'success';
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      return e.message;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "when I run the auth code nothing happens", can you post where you actually execute the code?

Comment: I have a button that calls `signInWithGoogle`. When I press it nothing happens.